# Dynamically set Client URLs on Keycloak Startup

Tags: docker, keycloak

In Keycloak there is already a way to export the whole realm with all clients, users, roles etc.
This results in a `file` that can be used to import that realm during keycloak startup. This works like a charm, but the problem is that the URLs of the `clients` in keycloak are hardcoded, in my case to `localhost`.

I'm looking for a way to set the Base URLs of the clients dynamically, in order to deploy keycloak with an imported realm and everything works out of the box. Unfortunately, Keycloak doesnt seem to allow environment variables in the client configuration using the Keycloak Admin Dashboard.
As a consequence, using environment variables in the `realm-export.json` itself is also not allowed :/

The docker container of `keycloak` (`jboss/keycloak`) does not even have `envsubst`. Its really frustrating to already have a json file that does most of the configuration at container startup when I still have to manually configure the client URLs afterwards.

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can build your own container image based on the keycloak image that *does* include `envsubst`. You can use `sed` to perform substitutions instead. There are lots of ways to produce configuration files from templates.

Comment: Sure, but I have hoped there would be another solution as this adds an extra logical layer to the import process... But i guess its the only option right now, as ENVs are apparently not supported :/